# how to create a dictionary from a DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame with 2 columns. how I can create a dictionary whose the first column to be key and the second column to be value?

Comment: `dict(zip(df[col_1], df[col2]))`?

Comment: OR `df.set_index(col_1)[col_2].to_dict()`

Comment: Or, `dict(df.to_dict('split')["data"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-dict) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
dict(zip(df.col1,df.col2))
```

Comment: In the key values I wanna remove everything after `,` . Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: @OP - Provide an example of a key and value please

Comment: @Nagh Please post this as a different question.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal for example `{a : BSc , d} ` . I wanna remove everything after ` ,` . So the output is: `{a: BSc}

Comment: @TimurShtatland I am not allowed. someone gave me a negative rate.